# What's a fast and simple way to change a CSV sort order from a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, csv

I have some CSVs with many columns per record; some are integers, some are (short) quoted strings. All CSVs have the same columns (and data types in the columns). Suppose the column names are c1,c2,c3,c4 for simplicity.

My CSVs are are now sorted by columns c1, then c3, then c2 (i.e. not a lexicographic order of the record strings in the file); I want to re-sort them in order c1-c4-c2. What would be a fast and simple way to do that in a bash script?

Notes:

- Both orders are total, i.e. no two records have the same c1, c3 and c2, nor the same c1, c4 and c2 combinations.
- I intentionally gave an example with the first column being first in the order since that's my specific scenario, but it's up to you whether or not you want to make that assumption.
- You can claim the only thing to do is to write a program in another language to do this (although I'm hoping for a different answer of course).
- The strings don't have escaped quotes or any other craziness, so the parsing is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no quoted commas, `sort` should be enough:

```
sort -t, -k1,1 -k4,4 -k2,2 file.csv > sorted.csv
```

Comment: Ah... sort can do that... ok, but what about the fact that some fields are  numeric and others aren't?

Comment: Also, what if some numbers are enclosed in quotes?

Comment: @einpoklum: for numeric fields, add `n`: `-k4,4n`.

Comment: @einpoklum: To sort quoted numbers as numbers, you need to preprocess the input to remove the quotes, then use the `-kX,Xn` to turn on numeric sort, then postprocess the output to add the quotes. It might be possible to do it in a pipeline.